# How can we disable the start of music player in android phone , when headset button is pressed?

Tags: android

In some of the Samsung galaxy mobile, when we press the headset button, the Music player is started. I want to disable this functionality. On pressing the headset button, I want to do another task.

How can I achieve this?

The `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` is received only in My application and music player should not receive the inten. So that the music player is not started and I will do what I wanted to do in my application.

Comment: I would be happy with just a way to ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bit late but this can be useful for others.

In manifest file set your intent filter priority to "high" (android:priority). I think highest possible value by documentation is 999.

```
<receiver android:name="media_button">      
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then in your receiver code abort broadcast to other intents. You can do this by calling [abortBroadcast()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#abortBroadcast%28%29) function.

```
  public class media_button extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        //your code ...

        //abort other actions
        this.abortBroadcast();
      }
    }
}
```